# What are all the timezones in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, timezone

So I am finding that there are different timezones in the salesforce marketing cloud across email studio, journey builder, contact builder, analytics, etc.

I have identified the following:

- System Timezone (Account Settings)
- Personal Timezone (User Profile)

Now i am wondering if there is a server timezone as well and what other timezones settings there are in SFMC?

I want everything to be GMT; from logs, to scheduler, to AMP Script, everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I admit, that timezones in SFMC can be confusing. Especially since there is a number of different timezones applied - depending on the area of SFMC you are working with. Here is a good unofficial (compiled in best effort) overview of where which time zone applies:
[image]
It is not possible to adjust the server time, which will always be UTC-6, so you will need to adjust accordingly in e.g. SQL or AmpScript

Comment: This is excellent.  Passing it along!

Comment: This is amazing thanks, where it says system date; does that refer to server time?

Comment: Yes, @Jordan - system date is server time

Comment: @LukasLunow What's your understanding of the System Display+Journey Builder and Data Filters/Queries+Mobile Studio entries?