# Automation time zone issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I scheduled an automation to run at 8am Eastern Time (GMT-5), but it says that the next run is at 7:00am.  I am unsure why it's different and not 8am?  Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: I have recently posted an [overview of time zones in SFMC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321962/36623) which you might find useful. As it shows, and in line with Swati’s answer, the next run is shown in user’s time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next run time in the automation is as per the user's time zone that is logged in. You can check the time zone of the user by clicking on the user name on top right.

> Cloud Preference>User Settings.